# Find the difference between the number of rows and columns of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $B$ be an $n$ by $r$ matrix and let $M$ be the block matrix: \begin{pmatrix} 0 &B\\ B^t & 0  \end{pmatrix}

$M$ has nullity 1. Show that the difference between the number of rows and columns of $B$ is 1.

I am supposed to use the fact that row rank = column rank for matrices over R, however I have no idea where to start.

Comment: How are the nullities of $B$ and $B^t$ related?

Comment: Since their ranks are equal then Null(B)= Null(B^t)+r-n